# CKAN: Not success in uploading large resource files

Tags: ckan

I'm using ckan 2.8.3.
I already changed config in ini to 100
(ckan.max_resource_size = 100)

I also update datapusher_settings.py to support 100 MB file.

I can successfully upload small resource files such as 1 MB, 3 MB.
But I cannot uploading large files (such as 6 MB, 10 MB, 18 MB)

I found this error in Datastore status log.

> Error: CKAN DataStore bad response. Status code: 409 CONFLICT. At:
> https://xxx.xxx/api/3/action/datastore_create. HTTP status code: 409
> Response: {"help":
> "https://xxx.xxx/api/3/action/help_show?name=datastore_create",
> "success": false, "error": {"records": ["unexpected data beyond EOF in
> block 1518 of relation base/16387/84705"], ... Requested URL:
> https://xxx.xxx/api/3/action/datastore_create

Please advise.

Comment: What format is your dataset? Also, do you have an additional extension enabled for validation?